# My image only shrinks when I shift it to the phone display

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, size

i have an image on my website and I want shift her on the right for mobile device.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .my-img {
    padding-left: 8em;
  }
}
```

My image shift well to the right but it shrinks ( decrease in size ).
and I can't make it bigger.

I tried this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .my-img {
    padding-left: 8em;
    height: 500%;
    width: 500%;
  }
}
```

Here it's my HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="assets/img/my-img.jpg" class="img-responsive wow fadeIn my-img" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
</div>
```

But nothing is happening. An idea ?

Comment: Can you add some HTML code too pls

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px)
```

Try setting the values to extremes to make sure they are actually applying

Comment: 500% is extreme, i'm gonna try to add 'only'

Comment: then the query is not applying, we can't tell from just this code, reload maybe? 90% of computer errors are typos so it's best to just check over all the spellings